# How to search subset of a pandas dataframe for the row in which a value occurs

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `dataframes`, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(10,3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
keys = np.arange(0, 10)
shuffle(keys)
df_data['keys'] = keys

key_data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.reshape(np.arange(1,10), (3,3)), columns=['Key_col1', 'Key_col2', 'Key_col3'])
key_data['Timestamp'], key_data['Info'] = ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'], [13, 2, 47]
```

Which returns, something like this:

```
    A   B   C   keys
0   3   9   2   5
1   7   9   4   7
2   9   6   6   0
3   9   9   0   9
4   8   5   8   6
5   2   5   7   3
6   5   1   2   4
7   3   9   6   2
8   4   2   3   8
9   6   5   5   1
```

and this:

```
    Key_col1    Key_col2    Key_col3    Timestamp   Info
0       1           2           3            Mon    13
1       4           5           6            Wed    2
2       7           8           9            Fri    47
```

I'd like to use the '`keys`' column in the first dataframe to search the only the Key columns in the second dataframe (i.e. `Key_col1`, `Key_col2`, `Key_col3`) (because the 'info' column may contain values that much keys).

I'll then add the columns `Timestamp` and `Info` to the row in which the there is a match for `key`.

Expected output for row 0  would be this:

```
    A   B   C  keys  Timestamp  Info
0   3   9   2    5      Wed       2
```

My approach is to first a subset of my key_df for a value:

```
key_data.iloc[:, 0:3] == 2

OUT
    Key_col1    Key_col2    Key_col3
0   False         True       False
1   False         False      False
2   False         False      False
```

In my next step I try to return only the row where the value `True` occurs using `df.loc`

```
key_data.loc[:, key_data.iloc[:, 0:3] == 2]
```

But this results in the error `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`

Can somebody help me to return the row in which the value `True` occurs so that I can use this index for selecting where to append my data?

Thanks

EDIT: The keys are unique and all of them are present in exactly 1 of the 3 key columns.

Comment: what happens if key column is matched with two columns i.e. key1 and key2?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal The keys are unique and all of them are present in exactly 1 of the 3 key columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for you, just rename the columns:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df_data, key_data, how= 'right', left_on=['keys','keys','keys'], right_on = ['Key_col1','Key_col2','Key_col3'])

new_df =new_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody help me to return the row in which the value True occurs so that I can use this index for selecting where to append my data?

The answer to this question is `key_data.loc[(key_data.iloc[:, 0:3] == 2).any(axis=1)]`, but for your larger goal, doing something with merge as Rahul Agarwal suggests would be better.